# Como ordenar questões de forma aleatória?

Tags: c#, algoritmo, unity3d, random, jogos

Estou finalizando um projeto de jogo Quiz Unity em C#, deixa eu tentar explicar o que preciso, já faço as perguntas aleatórias, porém eu quero que as respostas também sejam exibidas aleatórias.
tenho uma lista com 5 questões, cada questão tem 4 alternativas, as questões são selecionadas por um ID.
hoje o código esta assim:

```
            pergunta.text = perguntas[idPergunta];
            respostaA.text = alternativa1[idPergunta];
            respostaB.text = alternativa2[idPergunta];
            respostaC.text = alternativa3[idPergunta];
            respostaD.text = alternativa4[idPergunta];
```

no campo respostaA, quero que recebe um valor aleatório entre alternativa1, alternativa2, alternativa3, alternativa4.
por exemplo, o random diz que no campo respostaA.text recebe a alternativa4, então respotaB.text não pode receber essa alternativa, o random teria que gerar outra alternativa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
```

[...]

```
List<string> temp = new List<string>();

temp.Add(alternativa1[idPergunta]);
temp.Add(alternativa2[idPergunta]);
temp.Add(alternativa3[idPergunta]);
temp.Add(alternativa4[idPergunta]);

var r = new Random();

var c = r.Next(4);
respostaA.text = temp[c];
temp.RemoveAt(c);

c = r.Next(3);
respostaB.text = temp[c];
temp.RemoveAt(c);

c = r.Next(2);
respostaC.text = temp[c];
temp.RemoveAt(c);

respostaD.text = temp[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

O método mais prático:

```cs
void Shuffle<T>(List<T> objetos)
{
  Random r = new Random();
  objetos.Sort(Comparer<T>.Create((a,b) => { return r.NextDouble() > 0.5 ? 1 : -1; }));
}
```

Então:

```cs
List<string> objetos = new List<string>();

objetos.Add("A");
objetos.Add("B");
objetos.Add("C");
objetos.Add("D");
objetos.Add("E");
objetos.Add("F");
Shuffle(objetos);

foreach (var item in objetos)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Esse código pode ser simplificado: objetos.Sort(Comparer<T>.Create((a, b) => r.Next(2)-1));

Comment: Com essa otimização ganha-se uns 3~5 nano segundos por comparação. É uma solução prática e não a mais ótima. Com certeza é possível otimizar isso ainda mais sem utilizar o algoritmo de ordenação (que é meio estúpido ordenar de um jeito embaralhado LOL)

Comment: Acredito que a implementação do .Net seja um quick sort, que é N Log N, mas isso é facilmente linearizável.